# Minimum cost factoring in abelian groups

Tags: algorithm, haskell, optimization, combinatorics, finite-group-theory

I have a certain optimization problem, and I'm wondering if there is a clever approach for solving it. (This may well have been extensively studied and I just don't know what name to look it up under.)

I have a (EDIT: free) finitely generated Abelian group, `G`, on `n` generators. I also have a set `P` of elements of `G`, each labeled with a strictly-positive cost. All of the generators of `G` appear in `P`, so it is always possible to express any element of `G` as a product of elements of `P` or their inverses. The cost of any such product is the sum of the costs of the elements of `P` that appear in it, taking into account how often they appear. The cost of the nullary product, which expresses the identity element of `G`, is zero.

Given an element of the group I'd like a way to find a minimum-cost product that expresses it in terms of elements of `P`.

It's straightforward to translate this into a shortest-path problem without negative dicycles (on an infinite graph, but for any given element you only need a finite part of it near the identity element). It's also straightforward to translate it into an integer linear programming problem.

It may be that one of those translations is the way to go? Or does the additional structure of this problem lead to an easier way to do it? In my actual problems `5 <= n <= 10` and the elements I'm interested in never have multiplicities of any of the generators bigger than roughly +/- 20.

I'm working in Haskell, so functional approaches would be preferred to stateful ones, but stateful approaches are OK too.

Comment: I think with one generator, you get the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is known to be NP-complete. So I don't think you're going to find an efficient algorithm for this, sorry.

Comment: This is really a lattice problem.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, @DanielWagner. With the knapsack problem you don't have "negative things" like the group inverse provides. I think I am correct that this one can be expressed as a shortest path problem and you can use Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: @DougMcClean That's certainly true!

Comment: Oh, wait, then again there might be exponentially many vertices in the graph. I think there are, unless there is a clever way to choose a smaller finite subgraph of the infinite graph to look at, or a way to lazily expand it that looks at a sub-exponential part of it.

Comment: Sounds related to the [closest vector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#Closest_vector_problem_.28CVP.29) with an L^1 norm. I would ask the math stack exchange forum.

Comment: @Doug McClean Aren't the costs of inverse-elements also strictly positive?  One optimization by the structure of the problem is obvious, though: since the group is Abelian, you can prune the inverses of any element already in a proposed solution, as it can never be optimal to cancel an earlier step out at a strictly-positive cost.  You can likewise prune the inverses of the products of the powerset of your search path.

Comment: ***Clearly*** this question should be migrated to [CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com) or [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com)...

Comment: Or more generally: if *a* is in a proposed solution, all elements generated by -*a* in their minimal decompositions can be pruned from the search, as *a* + (- *a* + *b*) = *b*, but at a strictly-higher cost.

Comment: I assume the cost of the inverse of some element p of P is the same as the cost of p, and the only valid expressions allowed (to which we can associate a total cost) are products of positive powers of elements of P and their inverses.

Comment: Yes @AmitKumarGupta, that's correct on both counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Warning: Untested Pseudocode

```
This is pseudocode.  It isn't finished and probably won't even compile.

minCost :: element -> [generator] -> number -> Maybe [generator]
minCost _ [] _ = Nothing
minCost x _ c | (elemCost x) + c > cutoff = Nothing
minCost e _ _ = Just [] -- The factorization of the identity is the nullary product.
minCost x gs _ | elem x gs = Just [x]
minCost x gs _ | elem x ps = Nothing -- in P but not in gs.
minCost x gs c  =
  argmin
    pathCost
    [maybeCons g (minCost (x-g) [h| h <- gs, h <= g, h /= -g] (c+(elemCost g))) | g<-gs]

maybeCons :: a -> Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a]
maybeCons _ Nothing = Nothing
maybeCons x (Just xs) = Just (x:xs)

elemCost :: element -> number
pathCost :: [element] -> number
pathCost = sum . map elemCost

argmin :: (a -> n) -> [Maybe a] -> Maybe a
-- Return the item with the lowest cost, or Nothing if there isn't one.
```

There's a little bit of handwaving here, but the logic should, I hope, be clear.  We have to impose an arbitrary total ordering on *P* and `argmin` has to handle results of `Nothing`, representing that there's no way to generate *x* from that subset of *P*. My pseudocode doesn't have quite the right syntax to do this, for readability.

Excluding *h* > *g* from the allowed generators is safe, because any solution containing *h* would be found by the `minCost (x-h)` branch, up to permutation (and *G* is Abelian, so any solutions that are permutations are equivalent).  Excluding -*g* is safe because *g* + (-*g* + *a*) = *a*, but at strictly higher cost, so no such solution could be optimal.

The algorithm needs a way to prune branches such as, when *P* = {1,-1,i,-i}, testing (2+i) {1,-1,-i}, (2+2i) {1,-1,-i}, ad infinitum. This probably requires pruning the search when the cost exceeds a cutoff.  With that fix, it terminates because each recursion reduces the size of `gs` or the number of steps until *x* reduces to a generator, until it reaches one of the base cases or the cost accumulates above the threshold.  (This might be improved by passing up the lowest cost calculated on any parallel branch so far.)  It cannot repeat a computation because we have excluded the inverses of all previous steps in the path.

#### Afterthoughts

Saying that *e* generates itself even if not in *P* is incorrect by requirements and unnecessary for correctness: the algorithm never adds an element to its own inverse, so this can only occur if we ask explicitly how to generate the identity.  And that's a valid query: complex roots of unity?

On further reflection, thanks for the suggestion to represent the identity as the nullary product.  Otherwise, we'd fail because we never check generators against their inverses!  It has the right type, too!

There's a case to make the return type `[[generator]]` instead of `Maybe [generator]` and return all optimal productions, representing `Nothing` as `[]`.  The definition of `maybeCons` would become just `map ((:)g)`.  However, this risks exponential blow-up if there are a lot of equally-cheap paths.

Returning the cost along with the factorization, in a tuple, would both let us prune any later parallel branch with a higher cost sooner.  Or we could use `pathCost` for this.

The particular lattice structure of your group might suggest more ways to prune, although I'm not thinking of any others **in general**.  For instance, for the complex integers under addition, we can easily detect what the two (at most) generators must be just from the real and imaginary coefficients.  In many groups, we can easily detect that something is not a product of a particular generator by which subset of *G* it is in.  These could be additional guards that tail-recurse with a proper subset of `gs`.

The `generator` type has to be the same as `element` or an instance of it, because of the cost function.  The ordering relation might be defined only for generators, or their structure might be simpler.  It might have a different name if the group has a natural ordering that happens to be less efficient for the algorithm.

I'll leave in the note that the code isn't supposed to compile because I'm pretty sure I wrote at least one bug.

Comment: I think this is very much on the right track, but some things have come up and so I don't have time to try it for a couple of days. Just a note to say I appreciate the effort and will have more to say once I can really dig in to it. :)

Comment: On the afterthoughts part, why isn't the nullary product a good representation of the identity element? It is a free abelian group, so there are no complex roots of unity, and we can have the guards you are talking about to prune the `gs` that we recurse with.

Comment: Good point about the nullary product.  Will add.  Complex roots of unity was just the first example that came to mind where we care about the generators of the identity.

Comment: One note on this. We can compute from the given information in the problem what the cutoff to use is, because we know that any element `e` can be factored into the generators and we know that all of the generators are in `P`. This gives an upper bound on what we should be willing to pay for `e`.

Comment: I don't think it does, unless we also have an upper bound on multiplicity (or what's the upper bound for **Z**?), but I'm about to leave for Yom Kippur.

Comment: Yeah, good point, that was wrong. I was implicitly using another rule that the group generators are more expensive than the compound terms, which happens to hold for the instance of this problem that I am actually trying to solve. Probably more useful to solve without considering that rule in case it changes.

Comment: This does indeed work. I am going to use it as a baseline and see if I can make a faster branch-and-bound one using any extra info I can find about my specific problem. Thanks much!